# php form script

Tags: php, mysql, html, forms

I'm very new to PHP and am having some trouble. I have a form using HTML which is action=*.php* method=post

The form is using text boxes and select options, I'm not sure if it makes a difference in sqldatabase.  I've tried about 30 different combinations of this script and can only get a connect successfully message but nothing is posted.

```
<?php 
$link = mysql_connect('everybodyslistcom.ipagemysql.com', 'accounts', 'accounts'); 
if (!$link) { 
    die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error()); 
} 
echo 'Connected successfully'; 
mysql_select_db("user"); 
$FName = $_POST["FName"];
$LName = $_POST["Lname"];
$Phone = $_POST["Phone"];
$EmailAddress = $_POST["EmailAddress"];
$Month = $_POST["Month"];
$Day = $_POST["Day"];
$Year = $_POST["Year"];
$Username = $_POST["Username"];
$Password = $_POST["Password"];

$sql = 'INSERT INTO Members (ID, FName, LName, Phone, EmailAddress, Month, Day, Year, Username, Password) VALUES'
    . '(\'\', \'$FName\', \'$LName\', \'$Phone\', \'$EmailAddress\', \'$Month\', \'$Day\', \'$Year\', \'$Username\', \'$Password\')';

mysql_close();
php?>
```

Answer (score 4):

try to execute your query

```
mysql_query($sql);
```

EDIT: I see you are doing this:

```
$sql = 'SELECT bla bal $variable';
```

PHP will not parse the variable. The right way:

```
$sql = "SELECT bla bla $variable"; // valid
$sql = "SELECT bla bla {$variable}"; // also valid
$sql = 'SELECT bla bla '.$variable; // also valid
```

Answer (score 2):

your closing php tag is not correct, it should be

```
 ?>
```

rather than

```
 php?>
```

Also u r not executing your query using:

```
mysql_query('your query here');
```

this might cause the problem.

Answer (score 1):

1. Your variables are not interpreted by PHP. If you want variable to be parsed in string, it should be wrapped in double-quote (")
2. It may fail if any of your posted data contains some quote character, so you must apply mysql_real_escape_string to all of them.
3. I hope that database connection credentials are not real you posted here? :D

Answer (score 1):

You said that your form contains "action=.php" literally, you have to turn it into :

```
<form name="form_name" method="post" action="your_script.php">
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to execute the query too:
mysql_query($sql, $link);

Answer (score 0):

you should also check whether POST was really sent:

```
if (!empty($_POST)) {
    // ... your code here
}
```

next thing: you don't need closing tag ?> if your *.php file consist only PHP code - end of file is also correct end of PHP block of code - it's "good-to-have" habit, because in some cases it helps you to avoid error: "Cannot add/modify header information - headers already sent by..."

next problem - wrong way of inserting variables into string:

```
$sql = 'INSERT INTO Members (ID, FName, LName, Phone, EmailAddress, Month, Day, Year, Username, Password) VALUES'
. '(\'\', \'$FName\', \'$LName\', \'$Phone\', \'$EmailAddress\', \'$Month\', \'$Day\', \'$Year\', \'$Username\', \'$Password\')';
```

correct way:

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO Members (ID, FName, LName, Phone, EmailAddress, Month, Day, Year, Username, Password) VALUES (null, '$FName', '$LName', '$Phone', '$EmailAddress', '$Month', '$Day', '$Year', '$Username', '$Password')";
```

more [info here](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php)

next - as Deniss said, instead of:

```
$FName = $_POST["FName"];
```

should be:

```
$FName = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST["FName"]);
```

actually you should fist check weather [magic quotes gpc](http://php.net/manual/en/security.magicquotes.php) are on or off:

```
if (get_magic_quotes_gpc()) {
    if (!empty($_POST)) {
        array_walk_recursive($_POST, 'stripslashes_value');
    }
}
function stripslashes_value(&$value) {
    $value = stripslashes($value);
}
```

without this you could have problem with double \\ inserted into db (it depends on your server configuration)

and last but not least: as Robert said you miss one more important thing:

```
mysql_query($sql);
```

Answer (score 0):

I think your error because your have not call mysql_query function

can try my code edit

```
<?php 
$link = mysql_connect('everybodyslistcom.ipagemysql.com', 'accounts', 'accounts'); 
if (!$link) { 
die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error()); 
} 
echo 'Connected successfully'; 
mysql_select_db("user",$link); 
$FName = $_POST["FName"];
$LName = $_POST["Lname"];
$Phone = $_POST["Phone"];
$EmailAddress = $_POST["EmailAddress"];
$Month = $_POST["Month"];
$Day = $_POST["Day"];
$Year = $_POST["Year"];
$Username = $_POST["Username"];
$Password = $_POST["Password"];

$sql = "INSERT INTO Members SET FName='{$FName}', LName='{$LName}', Phone='{$Phone}', EmailAddress='{$EmailAddress}', Month='{$Month}', Day='{$Day}', Year='{$Year}', Username='{$Username}', Password='{$Password}'";
// Call Function mysql_query insert new record in mysql table
mysql_query($sql,$link);
mysql_close($link);
?>
```

Comment for me if your have problem :) or notes of apache services 
good day